# Run Multiple sas program in Crontab that that rely on eachother

Tags: linux, bash, sas, cron

I am trying to run 3 programs in my crontab. I get it to run, but the programs themselves fail because it looks like the session closes after each program.

Program 1
contains login/connection info to teradata

Program 2 
creates all macros needed for my 16 sas program process

Program 3 
first program in my process that requires the information from Program 1 and Program 2

How do I do this crontab?

This is what I'm trying to run:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Running Week 1 Day 1 process programs"
. ~/.bashrc

#changing directory
cd /prod/file/sas-data2/monthly_goaling_process/macros


#run base programs needed for programs
sas 00a_libraries_and_user_information.sas
sas 00b_imports_and_macros.sas

echo "Running Historical program"
sas 01_sales_and_credit_historical_pull.sas
echo "Historical program complete"
```

Comment: Create a single SAS Control Program that uses %include to point to each of the files and then use crontab to execute the single control program.

Answer (score 3):

You just have snippets of code and not full independent programs.

I think the easiest thing would be to add `%INCLUDE` lines into the third program to so that it becomes a complete program. Then the cron job only needs to run that program.  If you have other programs that also require those setup lines then make them in the same way.

Another way is to make a fourth program that includes all three and run that program instead.

You could also try using the `-autoexec` or `-initcmd` options in the command to run the third program as a way to pass in the code from the first two files.